# How to make onClearFilter to re-render originally received data?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have been stuck here for more than two days and have been trying, but now really confused and need advise/help.

I am working on a create-react-app (using Giphy API) that has a search bar and when the User searches for a gif renders like 10 gifs. I have added a "sort" button that sorts the gifs from newest to oldest. Now I am trying to add a "clear filter" button that would re-render the gifs *before* it was sorted. This is what I currently have:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      query: '',
      gifs: [],
      isSearching: true,
      isDataSorting: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onSortByDate = this.onSortByDate.bind(this);
    this.onClearFilter = this.onClearFilter.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(evt) {
    this.setState({ query: evt.target.value });
  }

  // ajax using axios to giphy searchendpoint happens here and is working
  async handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    try {
      // AJAX here with API key 
      const { data } = await axios.get(searchEndpoint);
      this.setState({
        gifs: data.data,
        isSearching: false,
        isDataSorting: false
      });
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    this.setState({ query: '' });
  }

  // this method is working great
  // when the sort btn is clicked isDataSorting becomes "true"
  // and in AllGifs component I have a conditional statement that
  // would render the sorted gifs (using utility/helper method)
  // if "false," just renders how data/gifs comes in from endpoint
  onSortByData() {
    this.setState({ isDataSorting: !this.state.isDataSorting});
  }

  // I am stuck here... I want to "clear" the sort that happened with onSortByData()
  onClearFilter() {
    console.log('Clear was clicked!');
    // initially, I had this hoping that it would re-render with
    // isDataSorting as "false" in AllGifs component...
    this.setState({ isDataSorting: false });
  }

  // isDataSorting, onSortByDate, and onClearFilter are all being 
  // passed down as props to my child component AllGifs
  render() {...}
}
```

I am stuck on the onClearFilter(). After the User clicks "sort" and onSortByData() changes to true and the utility method sorts the gifs by newest to oldest, I want the User to click "clear" and get the *originally* received data order or the data *before* the "sort."

Thank you so much everyone for taking the time to read this. 
Any advise, tips, or help would be AWESOME!

Comment: The `AllGifs` component is important, too.

Comment: Can you share the whole code including the utilty? This is too vague at this point.

Comment: The existing answer solves your problem. Just do `getSortedByDate(gifs.slice())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s difficult to pinpoint exactly what is going wrong here but I suspect that this issue may have something to do with the way in which you are sorting.

When you render the component you need to make a *copy* of your GIF array and sort *that* rather than sort the state object in place. You’d need something like:

```
const renderedGIFs = this.state.gifs.slice()
```

And then sort the rendered GIFs if the relevant flag is set. If the flag is false the array will be passed unsorted to the render function. But the crucial thing is that your state always contains the original array fetched from Giphy, which means you can always revert to it if you need to.